# Calling a function with arguments without using subshell - bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm not much familiar with bash. I have a scenario where I'm calling a function with a few arguments and assigning the return value to a variable.

Here's a sample code:

```
function f1() {
  if [[ $1 =~ $IP_REGEX ]]
  then
    return 0
  else
    echo 'Invalid IP'
    exit 1
  end
}

function f2() {
  # read ip from json file using jq
  local config=<read config>
  # validate ip by calling f1 if second argument passed to f2 is 'ip'
  [[ $2 == "ip" ]] && f1 $config
  echo $config
}

function read_all_configs() {
  pxe-ip=$(f2 'pxe-ip' 'ip')
}
```

The issue is when a wrong IP is detected, variable 'pxe-ip' is assigned the value 'Invalid IP' because **f2** is being called from a **subshell**, is it possible to **call the function with arguments within the same shell**?

Comment: You can't assign it to pxe-ip whilst running it in the same shell, there shouldn't be any difference in the way it is run though even in a subshell...

Comment: You probably ought to be writing your error message to stderr: `echo 'Invalid IP' >&2` (as well as reading sorontar's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the function to modify the variable:

```
f1() { if [[ $1 =~ $IP_REGEX ]]; then
           pxe_ip=ip
           return 0
       else
           pxe_ip='Invalid IP'
           return 1
       fi
}

function read_all_configs() {
    if f1 'ip'; then
        # do what is needed with a valid value of ip
        echo "$pxe_ip"
    else
        # do what is needed with an invalid ip.
        echo "$pxe_ip"
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose next solution:

1. Work with functions passing parameters: the function get parameters from $1, $2,... to clarify assign to local variable and work with that
2. Bash function returns 0 Ok, !=0 Error

Next code is how can be (I hardly understand what you try to do) but is aproximation of what you are looking for:

```
# 
# f(IP_to_check)
# return true | false
function f1(){
    local IP_TO_CHECK="$1"

   if [[ "$IP_TO_CHECK"=~ "$IP_REGEX" ]]
  then
    return 0
  else
    echo 'Invalid IP'
    return 1
  end
}

function f2() {
  # read ip from json file using jq
  # validate ip by calling f1 if second argument is 'ip'
  # f1 <ip>
  local MY_FIRST_PARM="$1"
  local MY_SECOND_PARAM="$2"
  if [ "$MY_SECOND_PARAM" == "ip" ]; then
      # do whatever
      # call your function f1
      f1 $PXE_IP 
      # If not OK-> IP invalid
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
           export PXE_IP="IP Invalid"
      fi
  fi
}

function read_all_configs() {
  f2 'pxe-ip' 'ip' 
  # After call f2 if IP is invalid global Var PXE_IP="IP Invalid"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use function as f2(IP_REGEX) as a

Comment: ı am new at this portal I am sorry abouth my presentation but this is gona help you this syntax for any fucktion for add attributes

Comment: ı am coder cause ı learn all thing at scholl and practise and youtube ı just know solution ı dont have link you can get something with this syntax, sorry bro for dissapponted stuation